# how write a sql request with sql rank function

Tags: cakephp, window-functions, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

How can I add this sql request (cl_rank) to my request  ?

My request (in class ClassementsTable) without the rank is:

```
$classement = $this->find('all')
            ->contain(['Users' => ['fields' => ['id', 'user_login', 'picture']]])
            ->select(['classement', 'points', 'participations'])
            ->order(["Classements.points" => "desc", "Classements.participations" => "asc"])
            ->disableHydration();
```

I need the cl_rank like this:

```
select user_id, points, 
RANK() over (order by points desc)cl_rank
from classements;
```

newExpr could be a solution:

```
$query = $this->find('all');
        $expr = $query->newExpr('RANK() over (order by points desc) cl_rank');
        $classement = $query
            ->where(['user_id IN' => $equipe])
            ->contain(['Users' => ['fields' => ['id', 'user_login', 'picture']]])
            ->select(['classement', 'points', 'participations',  $expr])
            ->order(["Classements.points" => "desc", "Classements.participations" => "asc"])
            ->disableHydration();
```

but some extra () are added around RANK() over (order by points desc) cl_rank  and the sql request is not correct.

The generated sql request :

```
SELECT Classements.classement AS Classements__classement, 
Classements.points AS Classements__points, 
Classements.participations AS Classements__participations, 
(RANK() over (order by points desc)cl_rank), 
Users.id AS Users__id, 
Users.user_login AS Users__user_login, 
Users.picture AS Users__picture 
FROM classements Classements INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = Classements.user_id 
WHERE user_id in (SELECT DISTINCT EquipesUsers.user_id AS EquipesUsers__user_id 
FROM equipes_users EquipesUsers WHERE equipe_id = :c0) 
ORDER BY Classements.points desc, Classements.participations asc
```

This one is OK (without the ()):

```
SELECT Classements.classement AS Classements__classement,
Classements.points AS Classements__points, 
Classements.participations AS Classements__participations, 
RANK() over (order by points desc)cl_rank, 
Users.id AS Users__id, 
Users.user_login AS Users__user_login, 
Users.picture AS Users__picture 
FROM classements Classements 
INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = Classements.user_id 
WHERE user_id in (SELECT DISTINCT EquipesUsers.user_id AS EquipesUsers__user_id FROM equipes_users EquipesUsers WHERE equipe_id = :c0) 
ORDER BY Classements.points desc, Classements.participations asc
```

Any idea to remove the `()`?

Comment: What's your exact CakePHP version?

Comment: cakephp version: 4.4.6

Comment: and the database : 10.9.2-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are supported out of the box (as of 4.1.0), they can be created via the functions builder.

There's shorthands for some window functions like for example `lag()`, `lead()` and `rowNumber()` (maybe `rank()` and others should've been among them), while others, and basically any arbitrary window function can be created via `aggregate()`:

```php
->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
    return [
        'classement',
        'points',
        'participations',
        'cl_rank' => $query
            ->func()
            ->aggregate('RANK')
            ->order(['points' => 'DESC'])
            ->setReturnType('integer'),
    ];
})
```

Any aggregate function can be turned into a window function by either explicitly calling `over()` (which will create an empty `OVER ()` clause when no further clauses are added), or by calling one of `partition()`, `order()`, `range()`, `rows()`, `groups()`, `frame()`, `excludeCurrent()`, `excludeGroup()` or `excludeTies()`, which will implicitly call `over()`.

See also

- **[Cookbok > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Window Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#window-functions)**

Comment: thanks @ndm I'll test and give a feedback